# Multiple file access using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am using multiple threads to access various random files using threads. However, I get an error `[Thread 0x7ffff7007700 (LWP 16256) exited]`. Also, info threads shows that only 2 threads are created. However, I am trying to  create 100 of them. Also, do I have to use the pthread_join() function in my case? The code:

```
#define NTHREADS 100
void *encrypt(void *args)
{
    int count = *((int*) args);
    AES_KEY enc_key;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &enc_key);

    int i;

    for(i=1;i<=count;i++){

    char *ifile;
    char *ofile;
    long length;
    size_t result;
    char * buffer;

    sprintf(ifile,"random_files/random_%d.txt",i);
    FILE *ifp = fopen(ifile,"rb");

    if (ifp==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

    fseek(ifp,0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(ifp);
    fseek (ifp,0, SEEK_SET);

    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*length);
    if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}
    result = fread (buffer, 1, length, ifp);
    if (result != length) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}
    printf("%s",buffer);
    fclose (ifp);
    free(buffer);
    }
}
int main(){
int i,j,count =0;
pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];

for (i=0; i<NTHREADS; i++){
    count = count +20;
    int *count_ptr = &count;
    if(pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, encrypt, count_ptr)!=0){
            fprintf(stderr, "error: Cannot create thread # %d\n", i);
            break;
        }
}

printf("After Thread\n");
exit(0);
}
```

Comment: 1. Join your threads in a followup for-loop. 2. You have a race condition. The same `count` back in main, that is changing with each loop iteration, is being addressed by *all* your threads. You're sending the same address to *all* of them. 3. *validate return results*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for your comment. Is it possible to send different vales of count to  the encrypt function for every new thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should join your threads, as none were created detached (and you're probably not deep enough in learning pthreads to deal with that anyway).

That said, you have a significant logic problem in your thread parameters. They're *all* getting the address of the *same* `count` variable in `main`. Probably the fastest way to change that with no modifications to your thread-proc is simply stand up a side-by-side array of `int counts[NTHREADS]` matching your threads, using each element as the corresponding thread's data param:

```
int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];
    int counts[NTHREADS]; // HERE
    int i,j,count =0;

    for (i=0; i<NTHREADS; i++)
    {
        counts[i] = (count += 20);
        if(pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, encrypt, counts+i)!=0) // LAST PARAM
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: Cannot create thread # %d\n", i);
            break;
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<NTHREADS; ++i)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Alternatively, you could do some dynamic allocation hoops, or send the value via `intptr_t`, cast to `void*`, but the method shown above has the advantage of requiring no changes on your thread-proc, a target I was aiming for.

I've left any issues in your thread proc to you to solve, but that should get you up and running on your thread stack, at least.

Answer (score 1):

There are missing things in the code, first, in your encrypt function you need to close the threads at the end and also in the main function BUT, before you do so, after your for loop you need to join them all, then they are going to be processed and closed correctly.

The flow will go like this:

```
(void) pthread_join(th1, NULL);
(void) pthread_join(th2, NULL);
```

You can put them all in a for to join them by tid.

Another update: There is not really anything "random" going on, I would just start open the files according to its tid, and then add other big implementations, your as is will try to open files like crazy, it should work anyways but, just saying.